# How to set Inbox by Gmail as the default email client in Safari (macOS)

Tags: macos, safari, email

I use Safari as my main browser on macOS.

I would like [**Inbox by Gmail**](https://inbox.google.com) to be my default email client so that it opens `mailto:` links.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not straightforward, but doable:

1. Open *Safari*, install the [mailto:](https://sites.google.com/site/mailtoextension/mailto.safariextz) extension, then go to `Safari > Preferences > Extensions > mailto: > Options > Custom URL` and add the following template:

   ```
   https://inbox.google.com/?to={to}&cc={cc}&bcc={bcc}&subject={subject}&body={body}
   ```
2. Restart *Safari*
3. Open *Mail*, then go to `Mail > Preferences > General > Default email reader > Select > Safari`

And you are done! Any `mailto:` link will now open the Inbox composer.